# How to stop a lye + oil + water reaction in aluminium container?

Tags: reaction-control

I was making soap using a guide for the first time. I accidentally used an aluminium container. It has lye and olive oil in it and was kept on the stove; now it is bubbling and not ceasing (I've turned off the gas).

What should I do to stop it?

Comment: Buy another container, I guess.

Comment: Tyler Durden used a stainless steel pot, I believe. Also, look for the liposuction clinic if you want to improve your product.

Comment: @andselisk I couldn't help but upvote :D

Comment: Fill it into an empty plastic can. I wouldn't pour it down the drain, lest it solidifies in your gutter. Probably won't happen with olive oil, but it's your bet.

Answer (score 1):

**Slowly add vinegar. *DO NOT TURN THE FLAME BACK ON.***

Most likely, the alkali concentration is high enough that you've dissolved away the passivating oxide on the aluminum, and the exposed aluminum metal is reacting with water to form $\ce{Al(OH)4-}$ and hydrogen gas.  Adding vinegar should bring the $\mathrm{pH}$ back down into a range where the aluminum can passivate again, stopping the reaction.

The batch of soap is probably already ruined, so I wouldn't worry about that.

In the future, I would recommend using a cast iron or mild steel (*not* stainless) pan for this procedure.  Plain iron is remarkable for its resistance to alkali, in my experience.

Comment: Since the batch of soap is lost anyway, we may just as well empty out the container and wash it. Chances are it is already damaged too badly, though.